# Past tense vs Present perfect vs Past Perfect tense difference in usage

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-vs-present-perfect

> 1. He **worked** for me for eight years

> 2. He ** has worked** for me for eight years

> 3. He **had worked** for me for eight years

What is the difference in meaning between these three sentences?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. He worked for me for eight years
> 2. He ** has worked** for me for eight years
> 3. He had worked for me for eight years

In 1), he no longer works for you.
In 2), he is still working for you.
In 3), at the time of a past event, this person at that time had worked for you for 8 years.

Comment: Then what is the difference between a)He has worked for 8 years and   b) He has been working for 8 years

Comment: No difference in meaning; the continuous tense just emphasises the continuous nature of the work.